# Prof A. Stanoyevitch's finite difference based PDE matlab code

Tags: pde, finite-difference, matlab, numerics

Where can one find Prof A. Stanoyevitch's finite difference based PDE matlab code? They have a book on such a topic but can't find the accompanying code.

Is it well received? It's not commonly talked about.

Comment: Why not ask the person themselves?

Comment: They are listed on his website for students of his university. I'm sure you could email him to request access.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth just curious if it's visible in public

Comment: @feynman Let me repeat this: "Why not ask the person themselves?" How is anyone here going to be in a better position to say whether something is visible to the public than the person who wrote those codes?